# SQL Exception:can not create table

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, sqlexception

when i run the code this error follows

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Can't create table 'Sensors_db.one' (errno: 121)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2624)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2127)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1362)
    at sensordev.SensorDev.sensorPage(SensorDev.java:283)
    at sensordev.SensorDev.main(SensorDev.java:893)
```

following is my my code

```
String type = "37";
        String senName = "one";
        String query;
        switch(type){
            case "37":{

                query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `"+ senName +"` ("
                        + "  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,"
                        + "  `State` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,"
                        + "  `Time` TIME NOT NULL,"
                        + "  PRIMARY KEY (`Time`, `State`),"
                        + "  INDEX `fk_dummy_1_idx` (`Name` ASC),"
                        + "  CONSTRAINT `fk_dummy_1`"
                        + "    FOREIGN KEY (`Name`)"
                        + "    REFERENCES `Sensors_db`.`sensorInfo` (`SName`)"
                        + "    ON DELETE NO ACTION"
                        + "    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);";
                defaultStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                 defaultStmt.execute();
```

'conn' is my database instance and 'defaultStmt' is a PreparedStatement

Comment: You are having an SQL error, you might get more info further down in your exception stacktrace. Anyway, I'd suggest you try your query directly in your ddbb. Hope it helps

Comment: if you see "basic error text" and some error number "(errno: 121)", then
the best next step is to google what that number means

Comment: Thank you so much .... @Vovka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`err 121` indicates that the constraint name is already used. Change your constraint name. Constraint name should be unique within your database.

To see if the constraint already exists.

```
SELECT
    table_name
FROM
    information_schema.table_constraints
WHERE
    constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY'
    AND table_schema = DATABASE() AND
    constraint_name = 'fk_dummy_1'
```

Answer (score 0):

fk_dummy_1 already exists in db

change your constrain name

```
"fk_dummy_1" to senName+"fk_dummy_1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the last statement to:`defaultStmt.executeUpdate();`